# Javascript coding for objects properties

Tags: javascript

```
var word = "Javascript"

var sentence = {
    construct:function(word){
        return ??;//`enter code here`
    };
    word:is;
}

alert(sentence.construct("Awesome!")); // Javascript is Awesome!
```

put the code in place of ?? such that the outcome is Javascript is Awesome!

Comment: what are you tying to do ? do you search for concat() ?

Comment: What is this for? Is this some sort of homework?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `variable` names. Also in `word:is`, `is` should be in quotes like `"is"`. Also replace `;` with `,`

```
var word = "Javascript"

var sentence = {
    construct:function(word1){
        return word+" "+sentence.word2+" "+word1;//`enter code here`
    },
    word2:"is"
}

alert(sentence.construct("Awesome!")); // Javascript is Awesome!
```

Example ***[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6nw2dom/3/)***.

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = "Javascript"

var sentence = {
    construct:function(word1){
        return word + ' ' + this.word + ' ' + word1;//`enter code here`
    },
    word:'is'
}

alert(sentence.construct("Awesome!")); // Javascript is Awesome!
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sr3dn25/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove "var" to create an global variable but you shouldn't do that because in javascript all code shares a single global namespace.

```
word = "Javascript"; //Removed "var" for creating an global variable

var sentence = {
    construct: function (word) {
        return window.word + ' ' + this.word + ' ' + word;
    },
    word: "is" //Added missing quotes
}
alert(sentence.construct("Awesome!")); // Javascript is Awesome!
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/z3h4Lma6/)

Comment: Thank you alex.. but by any means can we achieve it without removing the var keyword in the first line??